# Android Eclipse : variablename cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: android, eclipse, variables, toggle

i am developing an android application and have a togglebutton (id="tt") in one of my layouts. what i am trying to do is set an OnClickListener to that togglebutton. But i am getting the following errors in eclipse:

```
toggleButton cannot be resolved to a variable
onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
```

Here's the code:

```
public void ToggleMagic(){
    toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tt);
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      //        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed `ToggleButton` before toggleButton on second line.

```
public void ToggleMagic(){
   ToggleButton toggleButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tt);
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
      //        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add setOnClickListener to `ToggleButton`   as:

```
public void ToggleMagic(){

    toggleButton  = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tt);

    // attach an OnClickListener
    toggleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // your click actions go here
        }
    });
}
```

and make sure you are importing following Packages :

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View;
```